# Grab 5 days forward

Tags: mysql, sql

I am used to work with timestamps, I will attempt working with normal date 2011-02-02 12:00:00 format now

I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM users_calenders WHERE date ?
```

I would like to select everything where date is now to 5 days forward / in future

my date is in this format: 2011-08-26

So if it was the 21. 22. 23. 24. 25. 26. today,  it should show it..

If it was the 20. it should not show it as then there is 6 days to 26. august

Comment: what is `normal date`?  What dbms is this for?

Comment: I know that this is not what you're after, but it's spelt "calendar".

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users_calendars
WHERE   date >= CURDATE()
        AND date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

Comment: tried with curdate(), no errors although I have a entry with 2011-08-06 and it's 2008-08-03 today. It just gives me empty result

Comment: @Karem: sorry, missed the fact you want results in the future. Please try now.